# How to select a column in tabPanel with gxt3?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Please, i like to know how to setselection a column in a TabPanel with GXT3.
In Gxt2 there is the method setSelection(TabItem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
myTabPanel.setActiveWidget(myWidget)
```

where myWidget is the widget you have added to the TabPanel.

This works in GXT 4 and should work in GXT 3.

Comment: Thank you. Have an idea how to migrate MessageBox.info() from GXT2 to GXT3 or 4 ?

Comment: try AlertMessageBox.

Comment: Is there also a way to setIcon to the contentPanel in gxt 3 , thank's.

Comment: Do you mean the icons in the left upper corner? If yes, it should be possible to add those with cp.addTool(new ToolButton[imge]().